# Why do I have high a high bounce rate with a fancy design and lower with simple design?

Tags: seo, website-design, bounce-rate

I have a website that I previously worked hard on its design to attract visitors, but the bounce rate was more then 60%.

Then I decided to make it simple, and now I have a really simple design without colors or anything else, just simple text. But now my bounce rate is 6-10%.

My question is: do visitors like simple designs rather then fancy designs?

Comment: Generally, design is a huge part of bounce rate. Simple works. But making a site too simple, can signal lower perceived quality, price signalling, and trust to a user. It is a balancing act and marketing really comes in to play. Mostly, users do not want too much JavaScript flashy-jumpy stuff with pop-ups and annoyances. As well, they like a clean simple to use site. Over complicating a site can drive users away. Be professional in your design.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see that, bounce rate depends on how users takes time to visit and standby in our site. longer will be better.

If we get the this kind user, we get unique user. 
This can be caused by unique and useful content.
This will help to reduce our site bounce rate.

For some cases, using too many javascripts and fancy design will make site loading slower and this will cause user's bored to wait.
Even they straightly close the tab and find other references.

Comment: Agree with you. but in my case. i just changed the design. before this design. content was job postings. and now it is simple job postings as before. but after design i see improved user engagement

Comment: does the design disturb user from navigating?

Comment: i don't think so. in my opinion good design should matter user engagement. but it works with no design too. as we can see craigslist it has not design :)

Comment: I see your site just now and It's clear enough for information you serve. But is that one of the reason why user leaves early before reading a lot?
or, perhaps, it doesn't look like an elegant design?
By the way, I use CSS to design and animating and reduce javascript

Comment: but mostly user likes sweet design as you say :D

Answer (score 0):

For bounce rate only design is not responsible , Please check below possible reasons for high bounce rate :

1 - One page website - If your site is single page then google do not count page view until user refresh page. So here it is chance to have high bounce rate.

2 - Second it , how user behave with your website. Some users just comes to get your site URL OR to bookmark it , then it will also consider as bounce rate.

3 - If your site is loading slow and user comes to site , then because of slow loading user do not wait and close it , it can also increase bounce rate.

4 - Also design is factor there but it depends on user. some people like and some do not like.

So I suggest you that after your recent site design change if you can see that bounce rate is now less than before then you should concentrate on above 3 points and see content of your site also.

You should provide maximum user satisfied content via site. So when user search for something related to your site topic , comes to your site then he should feel that **"Yes this is what I wanted"** OR **"Yes this is for what I have been looking for"**

Content is just my example , there are many other factors might be in your site by which you can attract user and do like they stay on your site.